# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown> in recyclerview for below API 21

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, compiler-errors

I am getting this error. please check the layout in which I am facing this issue

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_ripple_effect"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_txt_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_ripple_effect"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_vertical_space"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_navigation_right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_space"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_space"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_space"
        android:text="Settings" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the java function where I am facing this issue.

```
@Override
public SettingMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_custom_menu, parent, false);
    SettingMenuViewHolder settingMenuViewHolder = new SettingMenuViewHolder(view);
    return settingMenuViewHolder;
}
```

I am getting this exception, when I tried to run it below API21,It works fine above API 21.Please suggest some idea to resolve this issue.

```
 01-12 12:58:36.362 3980-3980/com.kiran.example.ebitcoin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.kiran.example.ebitcoin, PID: 3980
                                                                          android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                              at com.kiran.example.ebitcoin.adapter.SettingMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SettingMenuAdapter.java:45)
                                                                              at com.kiran.example.ebitcoin.adapter.SettingMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SettingMenuAdapter.java:31)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `RippleDrawable` .`RippleDrawable` are only supported on and above API 21 . So you should move your `list_ripple_effect` to `drawable-v21` folder and make its equivalent(with same name) `Selector` drawable for Below API 21.folder name should be as 
 
**drawable** 
**drawable-v21**

Comment: perfect answer.